# Dask Bags run much slower than the serial computation

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I have a very large array (2 million cells here) and would like to perform a workflow for each cell in the array. Here is my test code:

```
import numpy as np
import dask
from dask.distributed import Client, LocalCluster
import dask.bag as db

# invoke 8 workers
cluster = LocalCluster(n_workers=8)
client = Client(cluster)

# test workflow to be applied to each cell. The real case is much more complex than this.
def g(x):
    np.sqrt(np.abs(x)) ** np.log(np.abs(x))

# test array with 2,000,000 cells. Values are normally distributed.
test_array = np.random.randn(2000000)
```

Then I perform this workflow using both serial and parallel computation.

```
%%time
# serial computation

results_serial = np.zeros((2000000, 1))
for i in range(len(test_array)):
    results_serial[i] = g(test_array[i])
```

This takes ~11 seconds to run on my machine. But for parallel computation using `dask.bag`:

```
%%time
# parallel computation

b = db.from_sequence(test_array, npartitions=24)
b = b.map(g)
results_parallel = b.compute()
```

It needs ~90 seconds to run on my machine, which is much slower than the serial computation. I wonder why we see this, and what are the suggested solution(s) to speed up the parallel case, either using `dask.bag` or other modules from Dask?

Here's the link to the notebook version of this code with more comments:
https://github.com/whyjz/dask-playground/blob/main/dask-test.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Dask Array](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/array.html) for parallelizing NumPy operations. It has better performance than Dask Bag in this case. It has a `map_blocks` function that you can use to call any function on each block of the Dask Array: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/generated/dask.array.map_blocks.html#dask.array.map_blocks

For your test code:

```
import dask.array as da

test_dask_array = da.from_array(test_array, chunks='5MB')
results_parallel = test_dask_array.map_blocks(lambda x: np.sqrt(np.abs(x)) ** np.log(np.abs(x)))
results_parallel.compute()
```